# Seaborn add percentage sign to barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to add the percentage (%) sign to each value in my barplot but I am not entirely sure how to do it. I know there is the get_text function that can help

```
g =  sns.catplot(
    data=df, 
    kind="bar",
    x="City", 
    y="Customers", 
    hue="Acquisition_Channel",
    ci="sd", 
    palette="dark", 
    alpha=.7,
    height=8,   
 )

g.set(ylim=(0, 100)) 
g.despine(right=False) 
g.set_xlabels("City") 
g.set_ylabels("Share of Customers vs. Total acquired Customers (%)")  
g.set_yticklabels("") 

ax=g.ax #annotate axis = seaborn axis

def annotateBars(row, ax=ax):
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate("%.0f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),

        ha='center', va='center', fontsize=12, color='gray', rotation=0, xytext=(0, 20),
        textcoords='offset points')

plot = df.apply(annotateBars, ax=ax, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
ax.annotate("%.0f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
```

you are using `string % data` which is not specific to `seaborn` but is used in python in general. If you want to put literal `%` just double it (`%%`), for example:

```
print("%.0f%%" % 95)
```

output

```
95%
```

If you want to know more read [old string formatting in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)